# Why don't connect and disconnect commands work on psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am new to postgresql. I've been using the psql tool to get familiar with the sql commands. Why isn't my psql installation recognizing the CONNECT and DISCONNECT commands?

[image: Why doesn't psql recognize the CONNECT and DISCONNECT commands?]

Comment: Where [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) did you find the `connect` and `disconnect` commands?

Comment: postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ecpg-sql-disconnect.html

Comment: That's the chapter about [ECPG - Embedded SQL in C](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ecpg.html). You should read the chapter about the tool you are using: psql

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to postgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead:  \c is an alias of sorts for connect under psql.

```
 \c mydb;
```

and

```
 \?
```

will give you some help as well.

Comment: Thanks, Is there one for disconnect as well?

Comment: well you kinda get disconnected when you \c to another db... it's a one connection system.  just so we are clear - these commands are valid within the psql utility, they do not necessarily correspond to the postgresql commands that you would have available within a connection from your favorite programming language.  for example, \d shows you the list of tables in your db.  in a programming language you'd have to query the schema info tables somehow.

Answer (score 0):

there are no `CONNECT` or `DISCONNECT`...
read:
[psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) and [SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) and [embedded SQL in C](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ecpg.html)

Postgres SQL commands are different from Oracle SQL commands

Comment: Ok. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ecpg-sql-disconnect.html What does this link specify? is that not a command?

Comment: no, no those are `C` calls. look at the name of chapter "ECPG - Embedded SQL in C"... You can't use thos directly in SQL request or in psql. as JL told - use \c in psql. and SQL you can run AFTER you connect to db. Please read my links